# How to make Jtable forbid duplicates

Tags: java, jtable

I have a Jtable allow editing and inserting.

When editing a column, lets say "ID", I want to have a check, if the inserted record or the record after editing have duplicat "ID" column value with the other records. it is not allowed.

actually, to be specific, if someone is editing the ID column, when he hit the "Enter" or move the focus to another cell, perform a check, if the ID is duplicate, then disallow the edition.

how can I do this?

Comment: Leon, you have two good answers in the comments above.  @Bala R and @trashgod - create answers so Leon can accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if someone is editing the ID column, when he hit the "Enter" or move the focus to another cell, perform a check, if the ID is duplicate, then disallow the edition.

Create a custom editor to validate the id before it is saved to the model. Here is a simple example to get your started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableEdit extends JFrame
{
    TableEdit()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(5,5);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollpane);

        //  Use a custom editor

        TableCellEditor fce = new FiveCharacterEditor();
        table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, fce);
    }

    class FiveCharacterEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    {
        FiveCharacterEditor()
        {
            super( new JTextField() );
        }

        public boolean stopCellEditing()
        {
            try
            {
                String editingValue = (String)getCellEditorValue();

                if(editingValue.length() != 5)
                {
                    JTextField textField = (JTextField)getComponent();
                    textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                    textField.selectAll();
                    textField.requestFocusInWindow();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        "Please enter string with 5 letters.",
                        "Alert!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(ClassCastException exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.getTableCellEditorComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            ((JComponent)c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));

            return c;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new TableEdit();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a custom `CellEditor`. The data model may reject duplicates, but the user needs the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Extend `DefaultTableModel` and override the add and update methods checking for duplication and use this class for your `JTable`.

Answer (score 1):

Extend [`AbstractTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) and arrange for it to contain a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.htmlhttp://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which precludes duplicate elements. As suggested by @camickr, you'll want a [custom cell editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062932/how-to-make-jtable-forbid-duplicates/6064558#6064558) to communicate the results failed additions.